# Saving an Excel workbook to HTML is not working in Windows 10

Tags: html, excel, vb.net

Saving an Excel workbook to HTML is not working properly in Windows 10. It is working fine in Windows 7.

Code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet 1 content"

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Test\csharp-Excel.htm", FileFormat:=Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml, Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CreateBackup:=False)

        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlApp)

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created successfully")
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please be more specific in _not working properly in Windows 10_ so that we may be able to provide further help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. On conversion from excel to html, actual content from Excel is not available in html instead it is having some strange text those are not in readable format.